# Close form using the cross button

Tags: c#, forms

I'm working on a C# project. I need to do the following but I'm not really experienced and I can't find it on the Internet.

I want to do an action when the user clicks on the cross button (for closing one form). I mean, if the user clicks on the "X" button on the top right of the form I want to use a method that deletes one file.

I just want to know the code for noticing that the user clicked on the "X" (close) button. I hope you guys understand my question. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Did you even attempt to do *any* research before posting this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537453/catching-the-close-event-on-a-c-sharp-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's user friendly to delete something on closing a form (especially as the 'X' button is understood as the close button by everybody who uses a computer), but you can override the OnFormClosing method of a form. Something like this:

```
// this will also close the form
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnFormClosing(e);

   if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

   // Do some stuff here (delete the file or whatever)
 }
```

If you want to alter the behavior so bad that the form won't close on pressing 'X', you could do sth like

```
 protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Cancel = true;

     // some stuff here...
 }
```

Which is very nasty IMO

Comment: even though the people voted the question too bad, this helped me a lot thanks so much! That was I was looking for!

Comment: Well, this site's purpose is for learning. What you have to understand though, is that you have to give your best in doing a little bit of research and trial and error before coming up with a question. This will help you understand how to put the questions better as well as solve your problems a lot quicker more often than not

Comment: Thanks that's what I'll do! @barca_d

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

> The FormClosing event occurs as the form is being closed. When a form
>   is closed, it is disposed, releasing all resources associated with the
>   form. If you cancel this event, the form remains opened. To cancel the
>   closure of a form, set the Cancel property of the FormClosingEventArgs
>   passed to your event handler to true.